# finding specifically where an object is for collision detection purposes

Tags: android, opengl-es, coordinates, collision

I have a square that rotates to a random angle and then travels in a straight line in the direction it is pointing. It does this by using a variable as its x axis and then calling

```
 Variable++
```

Each frame.

unfortunatley i cannot work out how to return the exact position of the square because the square can be travelling at any angle and therefore doesn't rigidly follow the world coordinte grid. This means that the x variable is not the shapes x coordinate.

How do i return the shapes exact coordinates and how do i do it in such a way that i can have two squares drawn from the same class behaving differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you've got a measure of distance from where the object started along its internal sideways axis and a measure of the angle between that axis and the horizontal?

If so then the formula you want is simple trigonometry. Assuming the object started at (x, y) and has travelled 'distance' units along an axis at an angle of 'angle' with the horizontal then the current position (x', y') is:

```
x' = x + distance * cos(angle)
y' = y + distance * sin(angle)
```

If you have the origin in the lower left of the screen and axes arranged graph paper style with x increasing to the right and y increasing as you go upward, that assumes that the angle is measured anticlockwise and that the object is heading along positive x when angle is zero.

If you'll permit a hand waving explanation, the formula works because one definition of sine and cosine is that they're the (x, y) coordinates of the point on the outside of a unit circle at the angle specified. It also matches with the very first thing most people learn about trigonometry, that sine is 'opposite over hypotenuse', and cosine is 'adjacent over hypotenuse'. In this case your hypotenuse has length 'distance' and and you want to get the 'opposite' and 'adjacent' lengths of a right angled triangle that coincides with the axes.

Assuming Android follows J2SE in this area, the one thing to watch out for is that `Math.sin` and `Math.cos` take an angle in radians, whereas OpenGL's `rotatef` takes an argument in degrees. `Math.toDegrees` and `Math.toRadians` can do the conversion for you.

Comment: To test your equations I have set the game to simply reset and start again whenever the edge of the screen is reached.  When angle is at zero degrees this works fine but at 45 degrees say it falls short of the maximum screen width.  I'm only using the value of x' at the moment because i'm tesing against the width of the screen.  Is there a better way of doing this rather than: `if(x >= screenWidth)`

Comment: Oh my bad, I didn,t feedthe angle in properly.  Doh!

Answer (score 0):

When you made the shape you should have already specified its X & Y coordinates. Im not too sure what you mean when you say you cant find the coordinates?

Also make sure you do fame independent movement; currently you are adding one to your variable on every loop of your program. This means if it runs a 60 Frame Per Second(FPS) it will move 60 units, but if it runs at 30FPS it will move at half the speed